# What are the units of the area of DIVA-GIS shapefiles

Tags: diva-gis

I've been checking several other post and even sent messages to DIVA-GIS, but still cannot figure out the answer by myself.

I want to know the area of a shapefile downloaded from DIVA-GIS: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata and sowmehow figure out the units of it.

So for instance, I got the shapefile for the US and extracted only the state of Alabama using R:

```
usa.shp <- readShapePoly("countries/USA_adm1.shp")
ala <- usa.shp[usa.shp$NAME_1=="Alabama",]
```

Then I estimate the area using `gArea()` function from `rgeos`:

```
gArea(ala)
[1] 12.867
```

And this is also the information provided to me in the shapefile:

```
ala$Shape_Area
[1] 12.867
```

But when I check about the area of Alabama in Wikipedia this is the information I get:

```
52,419 sq mi
135,765 km2
```

I haven't worked with geospatial data before and I would want to stranform this area to km2 if that's possible.

Comment: Area is computed in the units of the data. If you have data in EPSG:4326 (longitude-latitude) the horizontal units are degrees and the unit of area is square degrees. That's a lunatic area unit. Issues with computing lengths and areas for lat/lon data appear every week in this forum.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for the reply. I am using the `area` function of the `raster` package and I am getting areas that appear to be in mm2 if I transform then to km2 and compare them to the Wikipedia estimates. Do you think this is the correct approach?